# laravel migration best way to add foreign key

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, migration

Simple question: I'm new to Laravel. I have this migration file:

```
Schema::create('lists', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id'); 
    $table->string('title', 255);
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned(); 
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users'); 
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I want to update it to add `onDelete('cascade')`.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: 20 answers and [only one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29438715/1255289) actually answers the question of how to change an *existing* foreign key. Nice.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

**Inside the `up()` function**

First, make your `user_id` field an index:

```
$table->index('user_id');
```

After that you create a foreign key with an action on cascade:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

If you want to do that with a new migration, you have to remove the index and foreign key first, then do everything from scratch.

**Inside the `down()` function**

```
$table->dropForeign('lists_user_id_foreign');
$table->dropIndex('lists_user_id_index');
$table->dropColumn('user_id');
```

Comment: Why not: `$table->dropForeign('user_id); $table->dropIndex('user_id');` ?

Comment: I tried:   $table->dropForeign('user_id');
            $table->dropIndex('user_id');
            $table->dropColumn('user_id');  and it seems to have worked.

Answer (score 28):

In Laravel 7 it can be done in one line

`$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();`

Comment: Worth noting you could now also do `$table->foreignIdFor(MyModel::class)->constrained();` which will build the column name from the model name

Answer (score 18):

let's say you have two tables student and section , you can refer the following two table structure for adding foreign key and making onDelete('cascade') .

Table -1 :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('student', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('address');
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->string('about')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Table - 2:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('section', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->bigInteger('student_id')->unsigned()->index()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('student_id')->references('id')->on('student')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('section')->nullable();
        $table->string('stream')->nulable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

hope it will help you -:)
you can read the full article from [here](https://www.studywithkishan.online/2020/11/create-table-with-foreign-key-using.html) .

Comment: your link is not working!

Comment: Best link is the official documentation https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Answer (score 14):

As of Laravel 8:

```
$table->foreignIdFor(OtherClass::class)->constrained();
```

So simple :)

- Make sure that the OtherClass migration file is running EARLIER (by filename date as usual).
- If the OtherClass id is not autoincrementing, the otherclass_id would have a type of char instead of bigint, in which case->

Use this instead:

```
$table->foreignId('otherclass_id')->index()->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
```

Comment: That is a lot easier to use. Thanks for that. Not sure why the Laravel 8.x docs aren't updated to include this. 
Are the down functions still needed (like shown in the accepted answer) ?

Comment: @JanWillemHuising yes, you still have to define how to revert the migration, but that's easy.

Comment: Using `foreignIdFor()` alone doesn't add the foreign key constraints.

Comment: You need to add constrained() method after foreignIdFor to generate fk constraints. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Answer (score 12):

```
Schema::create('roles',function(Blueprint $table){

    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();

});

Schema::create('permissions',function(Blueprint $table){

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
    $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
    $table->string('permission');

});
```

Answer (score 10):

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

In this example, we are stating that the **user_id** column references the **id** column on the **users** table. Make sure to create the foreign key column first! The **user_id** column is declared unsigned because it cannot have negative value.

You may also specify options for the "on delete" and "on update" actions of the constraint:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')
      ->references('id')->on('users')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

To drop a foreign key, you may use the **dropForeign** method. A similar naming convention is used for foreign keys as is used for other indexes:

```
$table->dropForeign('posts_user_id_foreign');
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to add `onDelete('cascade')` on the existing foreign key, just drop the indexes and create them again:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('lists', function($table)
    {
        $table->dropForeign('lists_user_id_foreign');

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('lists', function($table)
    {
        $table->dropForeign('lists_user_id_foreign');

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should create a new migration file let's say 'add_user_foreign_key.php'

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('lists', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
         $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('lists', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
    $table->dropForeign('user_id'); //
    });
}
```

The run

```
 php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 3):

### Custom FK name using Laravel 7+

Those who want to add a foreign key with a different name while still taking advantage of the relatively new `foreignIdFor` function, you can achieve it like this:

```
$table->foreignIdFor(App\Models\User::class, 'author_user_id')->constrained('users');
```

This will add both a column and a foreign key constraint for you. Tested in Laravel 9.x.

### Nullable FKs

If you want your FK to be nullable, make sure you apply `nullable` **BEFORE** `constrained`, like this:

```
$table->foreignIdFor(App\Models\User::class, 'author_user_id')->nullable()->constrained('users');
```

Answer (score 1):

Clear and new in laravel

```
$table->foreignId('book_id')->constrained();
```

Answer (score 0):

**for versions before 7x;**

```
Schema::create('lists', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id'); 
    $table->string('title', 255);
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index(); 
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade'); 
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**for version 7+;**

Since this syntax is rather verbose, Laravel provides additional, terser methods that use conventions to provide a better developer experience. When using the foreignId method to create your column, the example above can be rewritten like so:

```
Schema::create('lists', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id'); 
    $table->string('title', 255);
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

The **foreignId** method is an alias for **unsignedBigInteger** while the constrained method will use convention to determine the table and column name being referenced. If your table name does not match the convention, you may specify the table name by passing it as an argument to the constrained method:

```
Schema::create('lists', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

source: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to make a foreign key

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score -1):

I was doing the same but got error " id not exist" => so I changed my migration file as below :

question table migration content:

**$table->id() => should change to $table->increments('id')**

definitions of foreign key in Reply table:

**$table->foreign('question_id')->references('id')->on('questions')->onDelete('cascade');**

now  your foreign key will work.

Answer (score -1):

#### Clear, modern and Straightforward approach

suppose parent: `Book Model` and `books table` 
suppose child : `Page Model` and `pages table`

```php
$table->foreignId('book_id')->references('id')->on('books');
```

where `book_id` is is the colomn name in child (pages table) 
and `id` is the linkage between the Parent and Child tables, books and pages tables, 
 and `books` is the table name to which we are going to link

Answer (score -1):

**Add Following two lines it will work perfectly .**
make if datatype of **id** field is **bigint** in users table.
If data type is **int** then use $table->integer()

```
 $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
 $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE IN 2023**

I was facing the same problem in 2023, I'm using laravel 10x, so I create migration with this command

```bash
php artisan make:migration add_user_id_to_transaction_table
```

then let's say your up() method in migration file looks like this

```php
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::table('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->after('id')->constrained();
    });
}
```

and your down() method

```php
public function down(): void
{
    Schema::table('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign(['user_id']);
        $table->dropColumn('user_id');
    });
}
```

that's how I define it if I don't add `$table->dropColumn('user_id');`
right after `$table->dropForeign(['user_id']);` it won't remove the column when you perform migrate:rollback