# On Laravel I get the error errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel, and I'm having issues with Migrations.

The table name spellings are accurate but I still get the error.

The error states

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
>   `first_db`.`#sql-41c_2f` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
>   incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `fees` add constraint
>   `fees_academic_id_foreign` foreign key (`academic_id`) references
>   `academics` (`academic_id`))

The error points to this file below:

```
Schema::create('fees', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('fee_id');
    $table->integer('academic_id')->unsigned;
    $table->integer('level_id')->unsigned;
    $table->integer('fee_type_id')->unsigned;
    $table->string('fee_heading',200)->nullable;
    $table->float('amount', 8, 2);
    $table->foreign('academic_id')->references('academic_id')->on('academics');
    $table->foreign('level_id')->references('level_id')->on('levels');
    $table->foreign('fee_type_id')->references('fee_type_id')->on('feestype');
});
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like the constraint for `academic_id` throws this. It could be that the `academics` table doesn't exist, doesn't have that field, has that field but with a different definition (char, signed int, something like that) or something like that?

Comment: Foreign key column and reference column must be same data type, and in your migration `$table->integer('academic_id')->unsigned()` use unsigned like this

Comment: refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26437342/laravel-migration-best-way-to-add-foreign-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unsigned should be a function :

```
$table->integer('academic_id')->unsigned();
```

Answer (score 0):

This foreign column should be unsigned.

```
Schema::create('fees', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('fee_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('academic_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('level_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('fee_type_id');
    $table->string('fee_heading',200)->nullable();
    $table->float('amount', 8, 2);

    $table->foreign('academic_id')->references('academic_id')->on('academics');
    $table->foreign('level_id')->references('level_id')->on('levels');
    $table->foreign('fee_type_id')->references('fee_type_id')->on('feestype');
});
```

Source: [Laravel Database: Migrations Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#columns)