# Add foreing key in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Create a linking table *Users* and *Roles*

Here's a sample migration code to create a table:

```
Schema::create('users_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');

    $table->foreign('user_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('users')
          ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->foreign('role_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('roles')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
           
    $table->primary(['user_id','role_id']);
});
```

As a result, the first key is created, and with the second I get an error

> General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `users_roles` add constraint `users_roles_role_id_foreign` foreign key (`role_id`) references `roles` (`id`) on delete cascade)

So, what could be wrong in my code?

Comment: Only a shoot from the hip, but that might occur on type mismatch. Is the primary key (id) on your roles table unsignedBigInteger just like the one key you've created here?

Comment: Is this post relevant for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26437342/laravel-migration-best-way-to-add-foreign-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to create indexes on field that you want tot use as foreign keys:

```
Schema::create('users_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');

            $table->index('user_id');
            $table->index('role_id');

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('role_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('roles')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

           
            $table->primary(['user_id','role_id']);
        });
```