# Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table

Tags: sql, laravel, foreign-keys, migration

I try to migrate "comment" table with foreing key from "blogPost" table, so I had this error about foring key:
[image]

this is code error:

**SQLSTATE[HY000]:** General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel8`.`comments` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `comments` add constraint `comments_blog_post_id_foreign` foreign
key (`blog_post_id`) references `blog_posts` (`id`) on delete cascade)

**this is code migration Table "Comment":**

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->text('content');
        $table->Integer('blog_post_id')->index();
        $table->foreign('blog_post_id')->references('id')->on('blog_posts')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

this code for migration table "Blog_Post":

```
Schema::create('blog_posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string("title");
        $table->text("content");
    });
```

-How can I fixe it ? thank you

Comment: please copy also your code as text

Comment: also which datatype  has ID in blogposts, they must be the same

Comment: yeah, It the same, i have id() and intiger for foreingKey

Comment: usually they are biginteger not integer, that is why i asked see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64661735/5193536

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [constrained](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints).

> The constrained method will use conventions to determine the table and
> column name being referenced. If your table name does not match
> Laravel's conventions, you may specify the table name by passing it as
> an argument to the constrained method:

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->text('content');
            $table->foreignId('blog_post_id')->constrained()->index()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

You see the implementation of constraint() below.

```
 /**
     * Create a foreign key constraint on this column referencing the "id" column of the conventionally related table.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $table
     * @param  string  $column
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Schema\ForeignKeyDefinition
     */
    public function constrained($table = null, $column = 'id')
    {
        return $this->references($column)->on($table ?? Str::plural(Str::beforeLast($this->name, '_'.$column)));
    }
```

As issue facing because of `id()` method is `bigInteger` but you are using integer for `blog_post_id` in `comments` table

if you see `id()` implementation ,it uses `bigIncrements`

```
    /**
     * Create a new auto-incrementing big integer (8-byte) column on the table.
     *
     * @param  string  $column
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Schema\ColumnDefinition
     */
    public function id($column = 'id')
    {
        return $this->bigIncrements($column);
    }
```

Comment: Thanc you a ton, it's working now :)

Comment: to repley on this," As issue facing because of id() method is bigInteger but you are using integer for blog_post_id in comments table"  oky before I use bigInteger I used Intiger, and having the same issue..